# Split option to have the variable at the beginning instead on the end?

Tags: shell, variables, split

I have a file of 47 million lines, I want to split this into files of 2 million lines, but the end of the filename has to be the same.

```
split -l 2000000 test_F5.csfasta splitted_test_F5.csfasta
```

This split command gives me these files:
test_F5.csfstaaa, 
test_F5.csfstaab, etc

And I want these files:
aatest_F5.csfasta, 
abtest_F5.csfasta, etc

Is there mayba a function in split to do this, or another way to fix this problem?

Comment: I do not think this option is available with split command...after split, since the no. of new files are less(~ 24 filess), you can rename them after the split command is run.

Comment: What is the best way to do this renaming for all files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To rename those split files:

Currently the files are:

```
$ ls test*
test_F5.csfstaaa  test_F5.csfstaab
```

Renaming the files:

```
$ for file in test_F5.csfsta*
> do
>   mv $file $(echo $file | sed 's/\(.*\)\(..\)/\2\1/')
> done
```

After renameing:

```
$ ls *test_F5*
aatest_F5.csfsta  abtest_F5.csfsta
```